# Auto Increment variable value changes inside the trigger

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I am writing a Trigger as follows that fetches the value of an Auto Increment variable from a table. The idea is to check this value from another table that keep approved IDs. If a match is found then the transaction is permitted else rejected.

However to my surprise within the trigger itself, the value of this field changes depending on where the value is captured.

Following is the trigger script. When the value of AutoIndex is displayed in first RAISERROR it remains stable, however when the same value is referred in second instance i.e. within the IF BLOCK, it keeps changing. Please advise where am I going wrong.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[WIZ_TRG_DOC_APPROVAL]
ON [dbo].[InvNum]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @AID AS INT
DECLARE @APRV AS BIT
DECLARE @Msg AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @DOCST AS INT
DECLARE @ORD AS VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @INV AS VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @AID = AutoIndex, @DOCST = DocState FROM inserted

Set @Msg = 'This document is not fully authorised. ' + ' AutoIndex = ' + convert(varchar(10), @AID)
        RAISERROR (@Msg, 16, 1);

IF @DOCST = 4
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Dir__Approve FROM WIZ_DOC_APPROVAL WHERE DocIndex = @AID)
        SET @APRV = 0  --Approval record has not been created yet
    ELSE 
        SELECT @APRV = ISNULL(Dir__Approve, 0) FROM WIZ_DOC_APPROVAL WHERE DocIndex = @AID

    IF @APRV <> 1
    BEGIN
        Set @Msg = 'This document is not fully authorised. ' 
                    + ' AutoIndex = ' + convert(varchar(10), @AID)
        RAISERROR (@Msg, 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK;
    END
END
END
```

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: Yes, the trigger is called multiple times but the conditions are put there to handle this. However, after further investigation, I have discovered that control is be sent to the RAISERROR block even when "@DOCST <> 4" and "@APRV <> 1". 

Could you have a look and advise why the RAISERROR is being called even when the code block conditions are not met.

Thanks.

Comment: When the trigger fires after a statement like `update InvNum ... where AutoIndex > 42;` which values of `AutoIndex` and `DocState` do you expect the be captured by your first `select` statement? `inserted` and `deleted` will contain multiple rows, the trigger will _not_ be executed multiple times to handle each row one at a time.

Comment: The logic of this trigger goes like this:
1. The user creates a new Invoice (New AutoIndex ID is created) and hits Process button.
2. At Document Status is stored in field DocStatus which is set to 4
3. The Invoice can't get processed until it is approved hence I am validating for Approval status in another table WIZ_DOC_APPROVAL where the Approval is stored as BIT variable against DocIndex that carries the same AutoIndex as in Point 1.
4. Once the query finds that 
a) Document State = 4
b) Approval is given i.e. "SELECT Dir__Approve FROM WIZ_DOC_APPROVAL" 

The trigger permits